# Getting request.data as an empty dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-viewsets

I have a viewset like the follwing

```
class DummyViewSet:
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        variable_a = 5
        return another_api_end_point(request, variable_a) ---> request.data: {"a":"value1", "b": "value2"}

@api_view(['POST'])
another_api_end_point(request, variable_a)
    print(request.data) ---> request.data: {} 
    print(variable_a) ---> variable_a: 5
    return "Some Response"
```

Why I can able to see variable_a's value as it is but request.data as empty in other endpoint?

Debugging it for hours now.

If anyone knows the reason for it, please revert. It would be a great help.

Comment: An `@api_view` processes the request, and you here thus process it a second time.

Comment: Please provide all the code necessary to represent a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How are you calling `another_api_end_point`? How are you creating `DummyViewSet` objects?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean the second api overriding the request variable and making it empty?

Answer (score 2):

you can start with

```
request.__dict__
```

to see if the request is truly empty or you are just accessing it the wrong way.
Given limited info, You can try the following to get the proper data given request.**dict** is not empty.

```
request.body()
request.json()
```

Comment: Using debugger in pycharm.. Checked it already. Empty it is.